# How To Start PHP Loop According To A Tag Digit Or Comma

Tags: php, jquery

My a tag link look like `<a href="6,7,8,9" class="in_cell_start_marker"> 6 </a>`

So i want to achieve:

if have 4 commas then loop 4 input field

or

if have 4 digits then loop 4 input field

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I really find it hard to understand what you want.

Comment: i just want to catch 6-10 values and start loop in php and get 4 fields

Comment: Please explain in details. What are the input fields ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i just want to catch here comma or digit, if have six/four comma then it loop four/six  input field, i want to just loop input separately fields with this unique ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current input data, in jquery:

```
var array = $('a').attr('href').split(','); //get href value and split it via , to make it array

for(i = 0;i<array.length;i++){ // start loop and go to array.length
  //do your stuff
}
```

Working snippet:-

```js
var array = $('a').attr('href').split(',');

for(i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="6,7,8,9" class="in_cell_start_marker"> 6 </a>
```

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: @NabilSikder  explained in comments. please check

Comment: I have another query can you help me ? i posted it here yesterday but no response

Comment: @NabilSikder  first focus on current question, let us know what you want to achieve and my answer helped you to achieve your current goal or not?

Comment: its helpful, just tried cannot implement it because i am stuck on my previous question , this is the part of that question what i want to implement, i don't know its a right or wrong way